# Can someone recommend a reliable lazy loading JS plugin for IE6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

This plugin doesn't seem to do the job for IE6 with jQuery 1.3.2 ( haven't tested 1.4.2 ):

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: Help rid the world of IE6 with one line of javascript!
http://code.google.com/p/sevenup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the way Youtube does it is by `<img src="pixel.gif">`, I may have to adopt this for IE.